# How to implement Master/Detail

Tags: controller, routes, dart, master-detail, angular-dart

I'm playing with Angular & Dart to learn both technologies.
It seems hard to find good tutorial which use the latest version of Angular.

I would like to find a way to create a master detail page where the detail could be any component or a simple HTML file.

If you ever did something similar, I'd like to know how you implement that.

I've attached a screenshot of my app so far.

[image: screenshot of my page so far]

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the thing that is covered in the [Tour of Heroes](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial), which is a tutorial that is kept up to date by the AngularDart team.  It's too long to reproduce here, of course.

Comment: Hello, i may not have explain myself well. Let's say I load several menu from a config file / webservice call / folder of HTML file. What would be the best approach to display them ?
I think I may have to create a component with a htmlContent binded inside a div or a htmlUrl binded to an iframe. Do you think it's a good idea ?
(in my exemple, I load Page1/2/3 and Vue1 from a service. Page1/2/3 are supposed to be component but let's say Vue1 is an element hosted somewhere)

Comment: To any reader which look for the same stuff, the basic master detail page is demonstrated [here](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt5)
It doesn't cover the dynamic content part.